# Receiving 400 Bad Request error with Google Api Batch Request

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm having an issue with an Analytics API batch request that I am doing, it was working and now it isn't without me changing anything. I know Google are making changes to their batch endpoints and I believe this is what is causing my errors.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html

I am using the .NET client library with the AnalyticsService. Having read through the link above I'm fairly certain I've done what is needed for my batching to continue to work.

[Here is a screenshot of the .NET instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ali5.png)

I've upgraded all Google libraries to the latest versions, I've checked the AnalyticsService object and can confirm the BatchURI is no longer the Global HTTP Batch endpoint `www.googleapis.com/batch`, it is showing as `https://www.googleapis.com/batch/analytics/v3`, but I am still getting 400 Bad Requests. Is there something else that I am missing, or do I have to wait until the 12th of August when Google say the switch will be complete?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer this is problem? And can you post your code?

Comment: @Josh see my answer for more details, no solution or workaround just yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: I created an issue on GitHub, apparently it is an internal issue, currently waiting for a fix, see here to keep updated:

[GitHub Issue on .NET client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1619)